# iPhone7 and iOS 11 error for **native** iPhone apps: This app was not installed from the App Store and must be reinstalled manually

Tags: iphone, ios11

I just bought a brand new (more on that later) iPhone 7 from an Apple retail store, got it home, initial boot and install of the OS gave me the message **"Unable to install (app name) This app was not installed from the App Store and must be reinstalled manually."** for six separate apps. The icons are there (with a little cloud next to them), but the error (er, message) above appears when trying to open each of the six apps. Note especially that these six were native iPhone apps (GarageBand, iMovie, iTunesU, Keynote, Numbers, and Pages). iPhone7 is running iOS 11.4.1 (15G77). I've been told that this is most likely due to these apps being offloaded (iOS 11 feature) during a prior installation of the iOS on this specific hardware. Ah, a new phone, huh Apple? I don't want to believe the phone was not new, but does anyone have any info/suggestions to support or refute this claim? Will iOS itself decide on its own to treat certain apps this way and not initially install them completely? I will note that these apps will install properly if installed individually from the AppStore, but why should I have to do that for multiple apps? Is it normal on an initial first boot with **plenty** of available space on the iPhone to see some apps not completely installed in this fashion?

Comment: it sounds like a provisioning profile is incomplete. I don't have enough knowledge on the subject to actually give an answer, so i'll just make the comment that i suspect that it is in this area. But i agree it is strange.

Comment: Thank you aremvee.  Note these are NOT enterprise apps from a non-AppStore site, like a similar post on the site addresses, but rather native iPhone apps readily available in the AppStore that are not installing here.  Just FYI.  I'm being told by moderator or someone else that my question 1. has already been answered, and 2. is a duplicate question, neither of which is technically or factually correct if you study the two posts.

Comment: It sounds more like your first port of call should be a phone call to AppleCare, as SO is more for actual coding correction. But S.O. has its frustrating ways for a reason. The post they refer to may only have the same title according to the bot that served the notice, not necessarily the answer you're looking for. Best to delete the question quickly.

Comment: I understand aremvee.  I did chat with AppleCare.  The resolution to my issue was that when initially powering up the iphone7 for the first time, I chose to restore from a backup created on my iPhone6, and these 6 apps that didn't completely install are not, in fact, included with the iPhone7 anymore.  Resultingly, according to AppleCare, they install with an icon only, giving the user the "option" of deciding whether or not to install fully.  Simple answer that's not readily apparent when powering on with a new device.  However, I greatly appreciate your responses!

Comment: I think the downvote was a bit callous as your circumstance was unique enough to warrant the question. I restored it by +1 at least. Anyway now someone with the exact same problem will find out. Maybe you should provide your own answer for that reason